# The "Elephant and Apple" - Phonetical Spelling of NY(C) with normal letters

Tags: pronunciation, slang, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonetics, spelling-pronunciations

**Some toponyms change over time**:
Be it by pronunciation (Los Angeles, New Orleans) or by changing the wording/spelling to either make more sense to the speaker (the London district "Elephant and Castle" from "La Infanta de Castilla") or no sense in current language at all (like German *München*/*Munich*, from old German/Latin *apud Munichen* = *near the monks*).

---

I have a dystopian setting in the remains of NYC post WW3.
I am looking for a name that is rooted in the location while emphasizing how distinct it is from our world (an archipelago).

---

**My approach was** to spell the pronunciation of the acronym *NY* (New York City) as a written out name that could have naturalized over time, with **the *C* having developed into *Sea***, misheard over generations and much more plausible for the speakers in this world. (One written word, only normal letters, no phonetic alphabet, maybe a stress for accentuation).

However, as a non-native-speaker I was unsure about the inconsistent English spelling/pronunciation. Furthermore I had heard the *y* pronounced differently (as *i* and as *uh*). Therefore I chose to ask the question here to the language experts and native speakers and not on *Worldbuilding Stack*.

---

**As it turns out, *NY(C)* is not commonly used**.This actually makes sense as it does not shorten *New York* in spoken language (compared to *LA* for *Los Angeles*). In fact, *NY* seems even more laborious to pronounce than *New York*.
I am still wondering whether to nonetheless go with this approach (to keep the *sea* as part of the name).  The written abbreviation *NYC* exists in "historic" texts so there is the possibility (even though not the likelihood) that this name got picked up by the survivors.
My favourite NYC-rooted version had been ***the Enway Sea*** (thx to [cpit](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/413085/cpit)): A name fit for an interregional trading post *on the trade routes* of merchants from everywhere, bound for the floating markets on the massive, protected square body of water in the heart of the archipelago. The *en* could either be pronounced like the English pronunciation of *en route*, maybe even having the written name bastardized to *Onway Sea*. I even thought about pronouncing it the *Away Sea*, based on the (Canadian) French pronunciation of *en* (route). This offers interesting connotations to the vanishing of the old city and the *oasis* it offers as resting place for travelling merchants in the middle of the ocean. This will depend on the influence of the Canadian merchants and culture on the trading post.

While making up my mind I might go with a descriptive synonym, maybe the ***city that (forever) sleeps*** (under the surf) or ***sleeping beauty***.

Thanks for your all your input, correction, inspiration and help.

---

Honorable mentions

- The archipelago of *Enwy*   / ***the Enwy Sea***, thx to [cpit](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/413085/cpit)
- The archipelago of *Anwai*  / ***the Anwai Sea***, thx to [cpit](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/413085/cpit)
- The archipelago of *Enwigh* / ***the Enwigh Sea***, thx to [juhasz](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/319612/juhasz)

Comment: The question seems to be primarily a request for fiction-writing advice, which is outside the domain of this site. A small part of it is about the actual pronounciation of the abbreviation, but that part seems to be incidental to the purpose of the question.

Comment: @jsw29 I saw it more as a linguistic/phonetic/language experience question, even if I give additional information about the story to narrow down, why certain aspects make more or less sense. And I thought writing stack is more about publishing or story structure.

Comment: To make this an on-topic question for ELU, you'd have to ask things that have objective answers. We could tell you what people currently call New York City (both in and outside of the area), and also exactly how it is pronounced in GenAmE and in local accents (not very different). We _might_ be able to speculate on what the likely sound changes are, but that would be speculation, which is a nice addition to objective answers, but terrible as the main part of an ELU question.

Comment: As an aside, "en masse" is (in English) pronounced with a distinct 'n'. As this is fiction, anything goes, you can name it what you want. Looking for justification for some future possible pronunciation is gonna draw out a lot of opinions mostly about what 'sounds good'.

Comment: @Mitch It originally started out as a mere question about phonetics (I was looking for a way to write/obscure the pronounciation of "NY" with normal letters, the reason why I asked the question here in the forum of the language experts and native speakers, not on worldbuilding stack).

Comment: @Mitch I simply started to include the suggestions of the comments into the question to simplify the overview and to be able to discuss them. An example for that is the idea of the (miss)pronounciation of "en", an idea that I had later on and added into the question. I didn't think this was worth opening a completely new question and you were able to correct me on that. (I had listened to the pronounciation of "en masse" in an online dictionary, however that website is multilingual and seems to only contain the French/original pronounciation for the word, even in the English dictionary part).

Comment: @Mitch I think linguistics and the world(building) and culture are connected. If (!!!) I remember correctly, languages dating back to stone age cultures contain the root of "stone" in everyday words, because this is what these objects used to be made of (like saying "stone-axe" as the regular term for "axe"). Stone age in that context doesn't necessarily mean that the language dates back to the ice age, there were cultures that continued this way of living longer. (I made the word "stone-axe" up, I only remembered the principle, not the actual word examples.)

Comment: It's currently pronounced "en wye sea" by Americans. But over time, names have a curious tendency to be turned into actual words – consider *White's Town* in New York, which has been altered to *Whitestone*, as in the *Whitestone Bridge*. So maybe you could call it the "Endway Sea". (This idea is partly inspired by Tim Powers, who in a novel set in the future turned *Wilshire Boulevard* in Los Angeles into "Wool Shirt".)

Comment: As others have noted, no one really says *NYC* — people say LA, KC, and DC, and to a lesser extent SLC and ATL, but New York is simply "New York" or "the [C]ity." A more realistic progression might be found in the neighborhood, borough or suburb names, as Brooklyn has long been spoofed as Bwooklin and Long Island as Lawn Guyland and so on. What is Yonkers in 200 years? Turtle Bay? Spuyten Duyvil?

Comment: @choster: that could possibly change in the future, so having the "Endway Sea" still would make a nice puzzle for readers.

Comment: Since so few people, especially New Yorkers, actually call it "N-Y-C" more often than they do "New York," it seems to me the most natural evolution would come from "New York," like because of the Brooklyn accent, the name becoming "Ne' Yawk" or "N'Yawk" and then just "Nyawk" and then possibly getting shortened to "Nyock" and/or, with potential future Spanish influence on English, possibly becoming "Ñac" or "Ñaque."

Comment: In the TV show *The 100*, New York got called in Trigedasleng (a post-apocalyptic version of English) "Bran Iokapa"-- "Bran" the word for "new" (derived from English term "brand-new), "-kapa" the suffix for "city" (derived from English term "capital city"), and "Io" derived from "York." It was also nicknamed "Dedlon" (derived from the English terms "dead" and "land") as it had been hit by so many nuclear bombs that everyone there died, so many nuclear bombs that it became so radiation-soaked only *natblidas*, the few with a developed blood immunity to radiation, could go there and not die.